# Is it possible to access the values of SimpleForm fields during input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using SimpleForm to collect a new object and I'd like to use values that the user has entered into the form to populate values in a nested form. Is there a way to do this?

So far I've been perusing the SimpleForm docs and poking around with `pry` when the form is active – without much luck… My next guess would be to try to get at the values with jQuery, but that is entirely new ground for me. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestions about how to start getting my head around how to do it?

Comment: -I have added the js code along with the html code..Hope It helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your view:

```
<p id="output"></p> 
<%= text_field_tag :foo, params[:foo], id: 'bar' %>
```

This will set your custom ID.

And then in your `.js` file:

```
$("#bar").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#output").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

This will return a value of the input.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="get_value">
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" ><br>
  <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
</form>
<button>Get Value</button>
<div id="value"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#value").text($("#get_value").serialize());
    });
  });
</script>
```